# override the inline css of a web component

Tags: javascript, html, css

On our webpage we have an empty div which is filled via javascript of a webcomponent.
This is a medical questionaire of an external party.

When the div is filled there is an element called

```
#shadow-root (open).
```

Inside this element there is first a style element like

```
<style scope="something">
```

Then comes the html for the questions.
We would like to change some styling, like colors and font-size, from the webpages css file.

How can we override/overrule the styling from our own css file?

We have tried things like

```
:host .caption {font-size: 12px; }
:host() .caption {font-size: 12px; }
:host(.caption) {font-size: 12px; }
.ourdiv .caption {font-size: 12px; }
.theirdiv .caption {font-size: 12px; }
```

There are a lot of websites explaining how to make a webcomponent, but nothing on how to overrule/override the styling.

Comment: Did you try the `!important` syntax in your css? Example: `:host .caption {font-size: 12px;  !important }`

Comment: Yes, tried that too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom) ? 
 This has a deep explanation of shadow DOM. Here's what matters to you.

```
#shadow-root
  <style>
    #panels {
      box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
      background: white;
      ...
    }
    #tabs {
      display: inline-flex;
      ...
    }
  </style>
  <div id="tabs">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="panels">
    ...
  </div>
```

The styles inside shadow roots element will style the element.
Stylesheets are also scoped to the shadow tree:

```
#shadow-root
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <div id="tabs">
    ...
  </div>
  <div id="panels">
    ...
  </div>
```

Comment: I have seen this page, but it seems to me it is from the web components perspective, while I'm working from the perspective of the page that contains the component.